# select an event on the calendar (fullcalendar js) and highlight with different color

Tags: javascript, fullcalendar

I have several events in the calendar and I want the one you select to be highlighted, but when you select a new one, the previous one selected returns to the way it was before. This is with fullcalendar for javascript

Comment: what have you researched? What have you tried? Where are you stuck? Hint: 1) use the eventClick callback. 2) use JS/CSS to set colours on the events. Do you need any further help? It's unclear.

Comment: Hi, Can you please show us some of your code. Thats how we may look what have you done and further what you needed to do in your script.